# In d3 for javascript, how do you create different elements for your data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, binding, html-table

For example, in a html `<table>`, a `<tr>` may contain `<th>` and `<td>`. How would you bind data to a row selection that would create even columns as `<th>` and odd as `<td>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this doesn't seem perfect either, but there's always the html() method.

```
​var d = [['a','b','c','d']];

var r = d3.select('#myTable').selectAll('tr')
    .data(d);

r.enter().append('tr').html(function(d) {
    var i, s = '';
    for (i = 0; i < d.length; i += 1) {
        s += (i%2===0) ? '<th>' : '<td>';
        s += d[i];
        s += (i%2===0) ? '</th>' : '</td>';
    }
    return s;
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​);
```

Comment: Since it seems impossible to achieve the databinding with different element types, this way seems like an ok way to give up on d3 on the columns, still using it for the rows, and get the result needed. By using `each` instead of `html` you could even keep using d3 inside the workaround.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you're correct - there's no way to do this within the standard D3 idiom. Presumably this will be possible once `selection.append()` can take a function:

> selection.**append**(*name*)
>
> Appends a new element with the specified name... The name must be specified as a constant, though in the future we might allow appending of existing elements or a function to generate the name dynamically.

Hopefully such a function would take the standard `(data, index)` arguments, and would solve this problem. Otherwise, at the moment, there's no way I can see to create different elements off of a single `.enter()` selection - `.enter()` only supports `.append`, `.insert`, and `.select`, none of which can take a function argument.

You can get some of what you want by munging the data into tuples and double-appending to the `.enter()` selection, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/xuJ6w/4/

```
// munge data
var tuples = data.map(function(row) {
    var newRow = [],
        x;
    // create array of objects
    for (x=0; x<row.length; x+=2) {
        newRow.push({
            label: row[x],
            value: row[x+1]               
        })
    }
    return newRow;
});

var rows = d3.select('table').selectAll('tr')
    .data(tuples);

rows.enter().append('tr');
    
var cellPairs = rows.selectAll('.cell')
    .data(function(d) { return d; });
    
var entry = cellPairs.enter();
entry.append('th')
    .attr('class', 'cell')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.label;
    });
entry.insert('td', 'th + th')
    .attr('class', 'cell')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });
```

But as you can see, when the update is called:

```
cellPairs
    .style('background', '#CCC');
```

Only the last-appended nodes are updated, so the data hasn't been fully bound.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is making a `<td>` look like a `<th>` by applying a class based on the index of the data:

```
var d = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];

var tr = d3.select("#myTableRow").selectAll("td")
    .data(d).enter().append("td")
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .classed("thLike", function(d,i) { return i%2===0; });
```

CSS:

```
.thLike {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that can be a useful workaround for many cases, but there is a semantic difference as well, and the `table` case was meant as an example. I suspect there might not be any solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data

> Selectors can also be intersected (".this.that" for logical AND) or
>   unioned (".this, .that" for logical OR).

So, something like this might work for you. I haven't tested though (if this selection doesn't work, you can just add the same class to each of the TD/TH cells and select that with `TR .myClass`):

```
var cells = tableRow.selectAll("TD, TH").data(data);
cells.enter().each(d, i) {
    var cell = d3.select(this);
    cell.append(i%2 ? "TD" : "TH");
})
```

Comment: I tried this, but `each` on `enter` does not work. - "the entering selection only defines append, insert and select operators"

Comment: I'd raise an issue/enhancement with D3. I don't see another way around this besides the workarounds provided by other answers.